# How to deal with special characters in rest parameter values

Tags: 2013, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am working on REST call. Everything works fine but my column contains special character `&`

So rest call like below works:

```
http://mydomain/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/Items?$filter=ColumnA eq 'DAD'
```

But below fails:

```
http://mydomain/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/Items?$filter=ColumnA eq 'D&D'
```

I dont want to change my column values now. Any solution?

Comment: Check this - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/139856df-ed1b-44aa-ab78-42fdb4c10414/which-characters-use-to-replace-in-rest-api-query?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
"http://mydomain/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/Items?$filter=ColumnA eq " + encodeURIComponent("D&D")
```

Comment: Thank you Gennady for the answer. I tried entering the same in my browser URL and it did not work

Comment: Not at all. Try type additional quotes?.. "http://mydomain/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/Items?$filter=ColumnA eq " + encodeURIComponent("'D&D'")

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try putting the encoded value in directly.  Have you tried something like this yet:

```
"http://mydomain/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/Items?$filter=ColumnA eq 'D%26D'"
```

Answer (score 0):

`encodeURIComponent` should work. I have been using this method and it always works for me.  You have to add `D&D` in quotes.

Try below URL. Just a little modification from @Gennady G's URL(i.e. quotes are added around the filter value) :

`"http://mydomain/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/Items?$filter=Title eq '" + encodeURIComponent("D&D") + "'"`